# Date Range in Excel not working

Tags: c#, excel, date

I am writing to an Excel file from C#. One of my columns has date values. So I am setting the format as follows
       rg = xlsSheet.Range[xlsSheet.Cells[13, 20], xlsSheet.Cells[rowcount, 20]];
                   rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
                    rg.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 20;

But in the resulting Excel I can see values in the format YYYY/MM/dd and also dd/MM/YYYY

```
 2015/12/01 18:46:10
 2015/12/01 18:46:10
 2015/12/01 18:46:10
 13/01/2015 06:39:23
 13/01/2015 06:39:23
 13/01/2015 06:39:23
 13/01/2015 06:39:23
```

How to have a consistent date format throughout the Excel sheet?

Comment: This is occurring because the dates are coming in as DMY and your system's regional settings are MDY. The latter 4 dates are strings because Excel could not recognize a date with the 13th month. In fact, the first three dates are incorrect as they probably should have come in in as 12-Jan-2015 not 01-Dec-2015. You need to parse the date according to the correct regional setting or perform some manual string manipulation to get the date correct.

Comment: @Jeeped: Setting the NumberFormat is not sufficient? How should I set it to get the correct dates consistently?

Comment: Consistency depends on whether you know the nature of the date format coming in and the nature of the target system's regional settings. Proper text import routines like [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) allow you to specify specific column date style with [TextFileColumnDataTypes property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215749%28v=office.11%29.aspx). I'm sorry but I do not have a C# environment that I can test a solution on (hence my comments only posts).

Comment: @Jeeped: Thanks for your input !

Comment: Here's an old VBA trick which you should be able to adapt. Get the datetime string into the cell as text; using a number format of @ should do but you might have to use a `'` as a prefix character to force text. Just get the datetime string into the column as text. Next perform a TextToColumns, Fixed width on the column. You won't actually be splitting anything but you will be converting to a true datetime from a string and this allows you to set a DMY input format. Once it is an actual (numerical) datetime you can apply any number format you want to ti.